# Controling Jetbrains built-in server programmatically

Tags: node.js, webstorm, gulp, livereload, liveedit

I use WebStorm and it comes with awesome LiveEdit function, and it's totally much better than LiveReload, however it doesn't automatically register changes in all different types of files I'm using. It ignores changes in Stylus and Jade and I need to manually trigger reloading the page anyway.

*I guess because LiveEdit doesn't reload entire page, but only relevant parts, and Webstorm of course can't possibly know what needs to be redrawn on the page, when dealing with Jade or Ejs templates*

For that matter LiveReload feels to be a better solution.

But I was wondering if it's possible to trigger reloading the page by sending signals to "JetBrains IDE support extension" somehow?

So ideally `grunt-task`, or `gulp-task` (I'm using gulp) would watch files for changes and send signals (maybe to WebStorms built-in server) and extension would reload the page. Is that possible?

**Can you control Jetbrains built-in server with node?**

Answer (score 0):

No. The extension doesn't have the API
However, LiveEdit does normally work for Jade (no hotswap, of course - just page reloading). When Jade is compiled using a file watcher, live reload is correctly triggered. It also works when Jade is compiled with Express. What does your workflow look like? How do you compile Jade, Stylus and other files that aren't natively executed by the browser?

Comment: Jade and Stylus are used as Express middleware. I don't know why they wouldn't trigger the update, maybe because Angular pre-caches its templates, maybe because I needed to turn off caching in Chrome. I ended up setting tiny-lr server and in my watch task in gulp send requests to it.